# Is there any leaked information about the real purpose of the X-37B spaceplane

Tags: nasa, spacecraft-development, spaceplane, x-37, millitary

Is there any leaked information about the real purpose of the X-37B. It is said that it could be used as a multipurpose space-plane such as a spy satellite or demonstrating technologies for re-usability, reliability, test of new  propulsion technology for longevity, testing avionics, flight systems, guidance and navigation, thermal protection, or insulation  and re-entry systems. In previous space flights information was tended to be secret and not many declarations are done by Boeing, Air Force and NASA for the purpose of each launch or program at all. Most of information remain just as possible but not confirmed. So i was searching if are some proofs,kind of proofs such as confirmed declarations published by wikileaks for example or leaked by inside people of the program, if X-37B is used for spying other countries for example, intercepting or capturing confidential secret information of other countries, if X-37B is completely a spy satellite itself, if it testing new propulsion system then what kind of it is testing and keeping so secret to other agencies,or doing other experimental technologies what exactly new technology is operating.

Comment: I saw that question it is really helpful for possible missions that could be used.I wrote in to my question some possible purposes which are shown in wikipedia and some other sites but i was searching if are some proofs,kind of proofs such as confirmed declarations published by wikileaks for example or by inside people of the program if X-37B is used for spying other countries for example,intercepting information,or if X-37B is a spy satellite itself,if it testing new propulsion system what kind of it is testing and keeping secret to other agencies,experimental technologies what exactly doing.

Answer (score 1):

The official name of the vehicle is the "Orbital Test Vehicle", and there is an information sheet produced by the [US Airforce](http://www.af.mil/AboutUs/FactSheets/Display/tabid/224/Article/104539/x-37b-orbital-test-vehicle.aspx). The two stated purposes are:

> The primary objectives of the X-37B are twofold: reusable spacecraft technologies for America's future in space and operating experiments which can be returned to, and examined, on Earth.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-37#cite_note-USAF_factsh-5) has a pretty detailed list of some of the items that have been tested on the various flights.

The most likely candidate, as stated by [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3106293/Is-X-37B-secret-spy-mission-Air-Force-Amateur-astronomers-spot-mystery-space-plane-unusual-orbit.html), is that the space plane is being used to test technologies that will improve spy satellites. Such things could include camera testing, thrusters, surviving at low altitude, among others.